# Input text align with jquery and css on window 10

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with align input-text on page load via jquery. It will align the text value to right but not. It only work when I click then lose focus the text field.
I got this problem when testing on **window 10 with IE 11**, but it worked fine on window 7 with same version of IE.

Here is my jquery code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='NumericTextBox']").each(function() {
        $(this).css("text-align","right");
        $(this).val($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
<body>
    <input name="IdNumericTextBox" value="999"/>
    <input name="IncomeNumericTextBox" value="999"/>
    <input name="etcNumericTextBox" value="999"/>
</body>
```

Any idea will help, thanks!

Comment: Please create a proper [mcve] that shows the problem. Also, why are you setting this via JS to begin with, what about this is “dynamic”, so that it could not be achieved by a rule placed in the stylesheet to begin with?

Comment: Sorry.. This is my first time posting question on stackoverflow, thanks you for your advance. I'll edit it.

Comment: About the "dynamic", I have pretty much input named like (name + NumericTextBox) so I want to use jquery to apply css to these input. And somehow it worked fine in all environment, which I have tested so far, except IE11 on window 10.

Comment: You can use the same selector in your CSS, so if all you want is to align the text in those elements in a specific way, you can use `input[name$='NumericTextBox'] { text-align: right; }` or something like that, and don’t need any JavaScript.

Comment: Ohh thank you very much, you made my day. Sorry to trouble you more but do you have any idea why that jquery doesn't work on IE11 (window 10 only)? It still make me confused...

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working for me I ran the below in ie11 and it seemed to aligned right. not quite sure what setting the value to the value is supposed to do but...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name$='NumericTextBox']").each(function() {
        $(this).css("text-align","right");
        $(this).val($(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="NumericTextBox" value="545"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, sir! Are you using ie11 on window 10? It worked well on window7 and other web browser but only ie11 on window 10 didn't.

Comment: yes win 10. if you run the code snippet above on ie11 win 10 does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does. I affraid that my jquery version is not supported, because when I change the script link to your, it worked. Thanks.